# Adding comment to column when I create table in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, comments, ddl

How can I add comment to column in PostgreSQL?

```
create table session_log (
                UserId int index not null,
                PhoneNumber int index);
```

Answer (score 218, accepted):

Comments are attached to a column using [the `comment` statement](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-comment.html):

```
create table session_log 
( 
   userid int not null, 
   phonenumber int
); 

comment on column session_log.userid is 'The user ID';
comment on column session_log.phonenumber is 'The phone number including the area code';
```

You can also add a comment to the table:

```
comment on table session_log is 'Our session logs';
```

Additionally: `int index` is invalid.

If you want to create an index on a column, you do that [using the `create index` statement](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createindex.html):

```
create index on session_log(phonenumber);
```

If you want an index over both columns use:

```
create index on session_log(userid, phonenumber);
```

You probably want to define the userid as the primary key. This is done using the following syntax (and not using `int index`):

```
create table session_log 
( 
   UserId int primary key, 
   PhoneNumber int
);
```

Defining a column as the primary key implicitly makes it `not null`

Comment: Seems that PG not offers standard syntax for comment on CREATE TABLE clause... Why not?

Comment: @PeterKrauss: there is no standard for comments on CREATE TABLE statements (Postgres uses the same syntax as Oracle)

Comment: It seems that pgAdmin won't show column comments but this works in psql (shows them rightmost, under "Description"):

`\d+ my_table`

Comment: Rare to see SQL-comments, partly because there is **no incentive, the syntax is ugly and redundant**.  The ideal comment-syntax for programmers, less verbose and more human-readable, is like Hive SQL: **at CREATE clause**, [see here an example](https://discuss.itversity.com/t/adding-comments-to-columns-and-tables/18252).

Comment: @PeterKrauss: I completely disagree. We use comments all the time. And the syntax is neither ugly nor redundant. It allows you to _change_ an existing comment or add a new one with the same command. How do you change a comment if you can only specify it during the CREATE TABLE.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, sorry,  the suggestion is **not** to abandon a standard, it's just to add **optional COMMENT on CREATE clause**... You agree that an option would be beneficial?

Comment: @PeterKrauss: again: **there is no standard** for adding comments to tables, views, columns, indexes or constraints

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, sorry my  English, I'm trying an "imagine it" talk, to check your opinion. It does not exist, it is a **suggestion to add a new feature**, without conflict with the previous standard.