# Basic syntax for CREATE TABLE in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, ddl, postgresql-8.4, unique-key

I am working with PostgreSQL for the first time. I have this statement:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sequences (
  SEQU_NK   SERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  NOM_SEQU varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  PROCHAIN bigint NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (SEQU_NK),
  UNIQUE KEY IDX_SEQU_NOM (NOM_SEQU)
)
```

When I run it I get:

> ```
> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "KEY"
> LINE 6:   UNIQUE KEY IDX_SEQU_NOM (NOM_SEQU)
>                  ^
> ********** Error **********
>
> ERROR: syntax error at or near "KEY"
> ```

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtable.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sequences (
  SEQU_NK   SERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  NOM_SEQU varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  PROCHAIN bigint NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT "IDX_SEQU_NOM" UNIQUE (NOM_SEQU)
)
```

**[SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/11fa7)**

Comment: Please explain a bit ?

Comment: @xavxav:- There are two problems in your query. 1) You have defined the Primary key twice which is not correct. (`PRIMARY KEY (SEQU_NK)` is not required) 2) The syntax to create the UNIQUE constraint was not correct. Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks Rahul..One more question: Can we write comments in PostGre like this : "PASSE varchar(40) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'md5',"

Comment: @xavxav: it's either Postgres or PostgreSQL but never "postgre". Regarding your question to specify comments: see [the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-comment.html) or [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32070876/330315)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks... for the links... But could you please answer : Can we write comments in PostGre like this : "PASSE varchar(40) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'md5',"

Comment: @xavxav: please read the manual and the other answer. Both sources will answer that question.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name My tery after reading it is: "PASSE varchar(40) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL COMMENT ON utilisateurs IS 'md5'," which again gives error "ERROR:  syntax error at or near "COMMENT"
LINE 5:   PASSE varchar(40) COLLATE latin1_general_ci  COMMENT ON ut..."

Comment: @xavxav: Please start a new ***question*** for your new question. Comments are not the place.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE sequences (
  sequ_nk  serial PRIMARY KEY,
  nom_sequ varchar(30) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  prochain bigint NOT NULL
);
```

It's `UNIQUE` , not <strike>`UNIQUE KEY`</strike>.
There can only be *one* `PRIMARY KEY`.
A `PRIMARY KEY` column is `UNIQUE` and `NOT NULL` automatically.
[Read the manual.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createtable.html)
[Or, better yet, read the manual for your actual Postgres version 8.4](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/sql-createtable.html) - which tells you that <strike>`IF NOT EXISTS`</strike> is not yet implemented in version 8.4 (wait for 9.1).
Or, better still, upgrade to a current version of Postgres. [Version 8.4 has reached EOL last year.](http://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)
Aside: Don't use quoted upper-case identifiers, or you have to keep quoting them, always.